# How do I prove that $\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i -\bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y}) = \sum^n_{i=1}(x_i -\bar{x})y_i^*$

Tags: statistics, summation

We know: $\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})^2 = \sum^n_{i=1} x_i^2 - n(\bar{x})^2$ But I don't understand how we can go from this relation to the result in the title. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does the asterisk mean?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote
$$
\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i -x)(y_i - y) = \sum^n_{i=1}(x_i -x)y_i^*
$$
but I'm guessing that what you meant was
$$
\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i -\overline x)(y_i - \overline y) = \sum^n_{i=1}(x_i -\overline x)y_i.
$$
If my guess is wrong, then you at least need to explain what that asterisk means.
\begin{align}
& \sum^n_{i=1}(x_i -\overline x)(y_i - \overline y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum^n_{i=1} \big( (x_i -\overline x)y_i - (x_i-\overline x)\overline y \big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum^n_{i=1} \big( (x_i -\overline x)y_i \big) - \sum^n_{i=1} \big((x_i-\overline x)\overline y \big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum^n_{i=1} \big( (x_i -\overline x)y_i \big) - \left(\sum^n_{i=1} (x_i-\overline x)\right) \overline y \\
& \text{The reason this can be done is that $\overline y$} \\
& \text{does not change as $i$ goes from $1$ to $n.$} \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum^n_{i=1} \big( (x_i -\overline x)y_i \big) \text{ because the sum in the large $\left(\text{parentheses} \vphantom{\dfrac\int\int} \right)$ is $0.$}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you and I fixed the title.